# Is it possible for 3C5 in permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A school wants to form a team of 5 student from 3 group.Group A has 6 student, group B has 8 student and group C has 3 student.

a)How many distinct team of 5 students chosen from these students consist of 5 students all from the same group?

I am not quite sure of what the question is asking as it is not possible to do so because group C has only 3 students. There can't be possible 3C5 in this situation.

Comment: If you define $\binom{3}{5}$, it has to be $0$.

Comment: $\binom{3}{5}=0$

Comment: Although it is not possible for all five students to come from group $C$ notice that it *is* possible that all five students come from group $A$ and it is also possible that all five students come from group $B$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Does that mean in the question above i should ignore the student from group C since its not possible to do a 3C5?

Comment: If you choose to ignore them or keep them in the back of your mind or have them in the forefront of your mind, the result will be the same.  How you phrase what you do with them is your own choice.  They still exist, they are still there, but they will not contribute to the total number of arrangements being asked for in this problem.

Comment: There is perfectly good reason why we might want to include terms like $\binom{3}{5}$ in our calculations despite $\binom{3}{5}$ equalling zero, for example when making generalizations.  If we said that group $A$ had $a$ students, group $B$ had $b$ students and group $C$ had $c$ students, it is much easier to write that the total is $\binom{a}{5}+\binom{b}{5}+\binom{c}{5}$ without worrying about which if any of $a,b,c$ are less than five.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your explanation, Which means i have to add both group A,B and C despite Group C doesn't contribute to the result i do  still require to write them down? Thank you

Comment: Since you are selecting a subset, this is a combinations problem rather than a permutations problem.